# the application myapp(process com.example.package) has stopped unexpectedly please try again

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat

I had so many troubles with my android app. it can't run but now I could make it, unfortunately, I receive the error" the application myapp(process com.example.package) has stopped unexpectedly please try again) 
here is my log file

```
12-02 11:25:11.980: E/MediaPlayer(278): Unable to to create media player
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278): create failed:
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:645)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at com.mohammed.watzIslam.Mymain.onCreate(Mymain.java:27)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/AndroidRuntime(278): Shutting down VM
12-02 11:25:12.290: W/dalvikvm(278): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mohammed.watzIslam/com.mohammed.watzIslam.Mymain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.mohammed.watzIslam.Mymain.onCreate(Mymain.java:28)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Post the part of your code that is causing the error

Comment: how can I know which one....coz at the problem tab I got not errors

Comment: Line 28 in Mymain.java  -  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-02 11:25:12.300: E/AndroidRuntime(278):  at com.mohammed.watzIslam.Mymain.onCreate(Mymain.java:28)  Please post your onCreate()

Comment: Which means that your exception is thrown in the file MyMain, in the method onCreate, line 28.

Answer (score 0):

```
12-02 11:25:11.980: E/MediaPlayer(278): Unable to to create media player
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278): create failed:
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278): java.io.IOException: setDataSourceFD failed.: status=0x80000000
12-02 11:25:12.290: D/MediaPlayer(278):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(Native Method)
```

My guess is that you're trying to load a media file that's not there, or the file name is just incorrect.